# Sharing post in Facebook shows UTF8 invalid character �

Tags: open-graph

I try to share posts from my website.
The thing is the famous question mark diamond shows up on some of the posts description.
All the OG Meta looks good (using Yoast SEO), it's 'just' the text on the share post itself that has this � sign.
I understand it's probably due to some file not encoded in utf-8.
I've added `default_charset = UTF-8` to my `.ini` file but no change.
The `content-type` is also properly set to `utf-8`
I've also did a validation check on [w3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fsmartbyte.blog%2Fwhat_is_smart_home%2F) and didn't find anything related

The website shows up just fine with no weird characters, it's only when trying to share a post on Facebook.
How can I find the source for the wrong encoding ?

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: He @Cedon, one of the links is https://smartbyte.blog/what_is_smart_home/  Thank you

Comment: I just tried to share it on my Facebook manually (copy/paste URL) and all I saw were Hebrew characters, no �.

Comment: There is most likely an issue with your browser. Try changing it, or its encoding in the options. I don't see an issue either.

Comment: @Cedon I've changed the description so I'll be able to share it myself, now I've changed it back so you can see it. (there is nothing there more than Hebrew characters, no special sign or anything).

Comment: @JackJohansson I don't it it can be browser related since I see it on Open Graph Object Debugger and it pulls the data directly from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue.
UTF8 might produce a multibyte string (when using Hebrew characters for example).
Facebook truncates this string a post is shared to keep the description under max number of characters.
However, they might truncate a multibyte character in the middle which will result in UTF8 invalid character: �
This issue actually reproduces in all multibyte websites.
The only workaround I've found is limiting the `og:description` to Facebook's max number of characters (about 110 in comment and 300 in post) 
I've submitted a bug to Facebook OpenGraph platform and I hope it will be fixed shortly.

Comment: Sagi, can you please link to the facebook bug report here.

Comment: @MarkKaplun, sure, [have a look](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/162378074403385/)

Comment: Another update, Facebook fixed the bug and problem is gone.

Answer (score 3):

I think is not an problem in your WP installation. The site works as encoding UTF-8, also your feed etc.

#### Validating

For an validating of strings should use the PHP function [`mb_check_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-check-encoding.php). A small script should check your database tables, the content so that you have feedback about your data inside the database tables.

Also it the libraray [tchwork-grekas/utf8](https://github.com/tchwork/utf8) helpful, for finding problems also fix the wrong strings.

#### Fix them via custom script

However if you will only search in your database, search via a plugin for an strings should helps you. Alternative is an custom script, that check and fix them. I think the [forceutf8](https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8) library is helpful. The method `fixUTF8` fix your problems, if you have inside your data.

Alternative is also the library *Patchwork-UTF8* in the first abstract, see above.

#### mySQL Table Collation

Before you should check the Collation of all tables. You check their encoding by looking at the Collation value in the output of [`SHOW TABLE STATUS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-table-status.html) (in phpMyAdmin or Adminer this is shown in the list of tables).

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM <YOUR_DATABASE>
```

#### mySQL Variable

You can also check each variable, run the follow mysql command in your database to verify that everything has properly been set to use the UTF-8 encoding.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';
```

#### Convert

Convert the table to InnoDB and utf8mb4, the `posts` table

```
ALTER TABLE wp_posts ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
ALTER TABLE wp_posts CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

#### WP Config

Check the `wp-config.php`
`utf8mb4` is your choice since WordPress 4.2, full UTF-8 support.

```
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4' );
```

#### Links

- [Helpful post](https://www.toptal.com/php/a-utf-8-primer-for-php-and-mysql) about switch from a NonUTF-8 database to UTF-8 for more details in the deep.
- [Solving PHP MySQL UTF-8 issues](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/08/31/solving-php-mysql-utf-8-issues/)

Comment: thank you for responding. I ran the `SHOW TABLE STATUS` and it looks like I have multiple values across my database: `utf8mb4_unicode_ci
`, `utf8_general_ci`, `latin1_swedish_ci` (I think it's the security plugin tables) and `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`. The posts table is `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Comment: Just read about this a little more and it looks like `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` is the correct value to have, is it possible other tables affect the post text ?

Comment: Update: Just converted all `latin1_swedish_ci` tables to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` with `utf8mb4` character set and no change.

Comment: All you tables and fields should use a UTF-8 encoding. utf8mb is also ok, much more possibilities. Latin is always wrong, so that you should switch that.

Comment: thank you , as I've updated, I've converted all the tables to have UTF-8 collation and the problem persists