# WP character encoding error after sharing post on Facebook �

Tags: database

I'm running a WordPress website with a custom theme that's having some problems lately. After clicking a shared link on Facebook that points to my website, I sometimes get an **character encoding error**. I checked everything in the wp-config file and ran a database optimization + repair, but I still get notices from people that the page doesn't load properly. This *only* happens when the link is clicked from Facebook and the URL has some Facebook query string.

I saw [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/289840/sharing-post-in-facebook-shows-utf8-invalid-character) question, but this seems to be about the Open Graph posts description only.

[image: The error]

Does anybody have any idea what is the cause of this problem, and how to fix it?

Thanks a lot in advance! :)